# How do I get Lightroom to stop defaulting to Copy as DNG

Tags: lightroom-5

When I try to import into Lightroom 5.7, the import dialog defaults to Copy as DNG:

[image]

I never want to convert anything to DNG. How do I disable this? I looked in Lightroom preferences and Catalog settings, and I see no option.

The dialog doesn't seem to remember the last option, either.

Answer (score 1):

Create an import preset with the settings you want.  Once you create and use a preset, the Import window will default to it the next time you open it.